# How to prevent an image from being resized in Android

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

I am writing an application on android. I am downloading an image from the server and trying to set it as an ImageView background using setBackgroundDrawable.

```
Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromPath(path)
imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

It works but the image is resized (it is getting smaller). Does anyone have an idea about how to set an image view background without changing its size?

**Edit:**
I solved the problem by using:

```
File imgFile = new File(path);
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
imageView.setScaleType (ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX)
```

Set image scale type to Matrix it will scale using the image matrix when drawing.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I solved my problem by using 
File imgFile = new File(path);
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: ok no problem. please post your solution as Answer so other will get noted fast.

Answer (score 1):

Use these two properties:

```
 android:scaleType
 android:adjustViewBounds
```

Study about them in : [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)