# Setting ImageView divides Drawable size by two

Tags: android, drawable

I have created a dress up game app. After the user finishes dressing up his character, he/she can save it to the app's gallery.

I am using canvas and drawbitmap on canvas to generate the final image, which is then shown on the app's gallery. The xhdpi image size should be 600x900 pixels. When this image is shown in the normal android gallery, it is shown as 600x900 and it (got from info) looks big enough. However, when I show it in my app, it looks much smaller though the ImageView is set to wrap_content. Moreover, when dressing it up, it is also set to wrap_content and it looks bigger than the one in the app's gallery.

My theory is that because I'm trying to set it programmatically using 
.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));
and because the screen is xhdpi, it is dividing the size by two.

What can I do?

Comment: in which folder did you put the image file, and on which device did you check it on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent an image from being resized in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513510/how-to-prevent-an-image-from-being-resized-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely, you're testing on a device that is not `xhdpi`, but `hdpi` or `mdpi`.

When you provide a graphic in a density bucket, Android will take care of resizing that image so that it remains the same physical dimension across all devices (that is to say, size in cm on the screen).

If you would like to use the raw drawable, you can provide the graphic in the `res/drawable-nodpi` folder.

If you would like to retain the density buckets, but your graphic is too small, provide the correct sizes in `res/drawable-mdpi`, `res/drawable-hdpi` and `res/drawable-xhdpi`.

I don't believe there is any way of preventing this behavior through `Drawable.createFromPath()`. You could load the bitmap directly using `BitmapFactory` and provide it into the ImageView using `setImageBitmap()`:

```
File f = new File(path);
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
```

Comment: Using BitmapFactory.decodeFile solved the issue.
For interested people, I tried changing the scaleType, but to no avail. Using BitmapFactory is the solution.